# How to ensure thread safety when i have two processes that use the same file?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two different processes that share the same file , the first one is the Reader and the second one is the writer. I am using StreamWriter and StreamReader in c# but i have an exception "The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process".
How could I achieve thread safety ?

Comment: locking the resource

Comment: There is no need of _thread safety_ in your case, there should be an interprocess synchronization.

Comment: When you make your `StreamReader`, make sure you're using a constructor that accepts a `FileAccess` argument, and pass `FileAccess.Read`.  That should allow the reader to read while the writer is writing.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with thread safety, but interprocess synchronization. Use an interprocess lock (called *named [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx)*)

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution, for the writer I used:

```
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path))
                {
                   //WorkTodo
                }
```

And for the the reader

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path))
                {
                    //WorkTodo
                }
```